# Getting "object is possibly null" TypeScript error when using template ref value in Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, frontend

I am referencing an `<h1>` with `ref="header"`. I'm trying to change CSS rules but a TypeScript error is not letting me.

```
const header = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)

onMounted(() => {
  header.value.style.color = "red"
})
```

[image: screenshot of error message]

Comment: You could simply use optional chaining to `header.value?.style.color = 'red'`

Comment: I have this error doing that: The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.ts(2779)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is perfectly reasonable: you can't be sure that that element exists.
And if the element doesn't exist, the template ref's value will be `null`.
It's actually right there in the type for the ref: `HTMLElement | null`.

You can change your `onMounted` callback to the following to check for that:

```
onMounted(() => {
  if (header.value)
    header.value.style.color = "red"
})
```